# For bundle product how i get the Item(sku) in order email

Tags: magento-1.8

In magento for bundle product how i have to get the Item(sku) of bundle product in Customer Order email. For simple product it showing this Item(sku) BUT for Bundle and Grouped, Configurable product how i get the Item(sku) for this product. please help me out of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that complex product types in Magento are actually "virtual" products. They don't really exist. Only the associated or bundled products exist, and that's what is passed on when a customer orders. Bundles, groups and configurables are just means of representing two or more individual products.

While I think there's more work to be done in this arena, we did build an extension that creates a "Package" product type that *is* represented to customers as a singular SKU, while on the backend and on the Packing List, the associated items are represented since whoever is packing the shipment needs to know what all to put into the box.

I don't know if this will help, but you can read out our extension at http://goo.gl/UiY7yJ

Good luck and keep us posted on your progress.